# Get Image File Extension with PHP

Tags: php, file

The file name is known but the file extension is unknown. The images in thier folders do have an extension but in the database their names do not.

Example:

```
$ImagePath = "../images/2015/03/06/";   (Folders are based on date)
$ImageName = "lake-sunset_3";
```

Does not work - $Ext is empty:

```
$Ext  = (new SplFileInfo($ImagePath))->getExtension();
echo $Ext;
```

Does not work either - $Ext is empty:

```
$Ext  = (new SplFileInfo($ImagePath.$ImageName))->getExtension();
echo $Ext;
```

Does not work either - $Ext is still empty:

```
$Ext  = (new SplFileInfo($ImagePath,$ImageName))->getExtension();
echo $Ext;
```

$Ext should produce ".jpg" or ".jpeg" or ".png" etc.

So my question is simple: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The image files in question do indeed have extensions in their respective folders but the image names are stored in a database without extensions. I can retrieve the image names from the database but cannot retrieve an image from it's folder without it's extension. I have edited my question to make it a bit clearer

Answer (score 1):

Now, this is a bit of an ugly solution but it should work. Make sure that all your files have unique names else you'll have several of the same file, which could lead to your program obtaining the wrong one.

```
<?php
$dir = scandir($imagePath);
$length = strlen($ImageName);
$true_filename = '';
foreach ($dir as $k => $filename) {
    $path = pathinfo($filename);
    if ($ImageName === $path['filename']) {
        break;
    }
}
$Ext = $path['extension'];

?>
```

Comment: What if there is also a file named `lake-sunset_32.jpg`?

Comment: What you ask is true and can certainly be the case. The reason is that the original image names are replaced with an SEO string which is also used in other areas as a URL to a page for example. This is why in the database the image names are stored without an extension although in their folders they do have an extension.

Comment: It is possible to store images without their extensions or with a custom extension, so that apache/nginx can have special rules for them (such as showing them instead of sending them through ftp when directly accessed). All current browsers will happily read the file headers and interpret them correctly by the way. A better design philosophy in your case could be to store image names in the database with their extensions on them, then remove their extensions with pathinfo() when you output them.

Comment: Thank you Digits. I am trying this example now but still without success - example:

Comment: Thank you Digits. I am trying this example but still without success - example:

$ImageName = "lake-sunset_3"; 
$ImagePath = "../images/2015/03/06/";

$dir = scandir($ImagePath);
$length = strlen($ImageName);
$true_filename = '';
foreach ($dir as $k => $filename) {
    if ($ImageName === substr($filename, 0, $length))
        $true_filename = $filename;
}
echo $true_filename;

$true_filename still displays empty.

Yes would have been better to do this another way however the original design of the database/image structure is by Open Classifieds (open source code) and I am adding an extra page.

Comment: I made an edit to my code a while back, that is the previous version. There are probably some mistakes I made that could only be fixed if I were to return to the problem a few times and test it right on your server, I can't help you implement a full solution, at the most I can do my best to match your use case as closely as possible in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might help you (another brute and ugly solution)-

```
$dir = '/path/to/your/dir';
$found = array();
$filename = 'your_desired_file';

$files = scandir($dir);

if( !empty( $files ) ){
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        if( $file == '.' || $file == '..' || $file == '' ){
            continue;
        }

        $info = pathinfo( $file );

        if( $info['filename'] == $filename ){
            $found = $info;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// if file name is matched, $found variable will contain the path, basename, filename and the extension of the file you are looking for
```

**EDIT**

If you just want the uri of your image then you need to take care of 2 things. First `directory path` and `directory uri` are not the same thing. If you need to work with file then you must use `directory path`. And to serve static files such as images then you must use `directory uri`. That means if you need to check files exists or what then you must use `/absolute/path/to/your/image` and in case of image `[site_uri]/path/to/your/image/filename`. See the differences? The $found variable form the example above is an array-

```
$found = array(
    'dirname' => 'path/to/your/file',
    'basename' => 'yourfilename.extension',
    'filename' => 'yourfilename',
    'extension' => 'fileextension'
);

// to retrieve the uri from the path.. if you use a CMS then you don't need to worry about that, just get the uri of that directory.

function path2url( $file, $Protocol='http://' ) {
    return $Protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $file);
}

$image_url = path2url( $found['dirname'] . $found['basename'] ); // you should get the correct image url at this moment.
```

Comment: Thank you maksbd19 - this answer runs but echo $found; only produces the word "Array" (without quotes).

Comment: Hmmmm, quite strange. I have been through all the answers above again and none of them work - zero results. I don't mean that as criticism, and I thank you all for your time and answers - I just find it strange that $ImagePath . $ImageName . ".jpg" produces the correct image result yet echoing any result from the code in the answers above does not produce any results - empty output. Scratching head... very strange...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a file named `lake-sunset_3`.   It has no extension.

`SplFileInfo::getExtension()` is not designed to do what you are requesting it to do.

From the php site:

> Returns a string containing the file extension, or an empty string if the file has no extension.

http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php

Instead you can do something like this:

```
$path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Thank you nomistic - I have tried this also but without success

Answer (score 0):

`getExtension()` only returns the extension from the given path, which in your case of course doesn't have one.

In general, this is not possible. What if there is a file `lake-sunset_3.jpg` and a file `lake-sunset_3.png`?

The only thing you can do is scan the directory and look for a file with that name but any extension.

Comment: Yes Jimmy T you are correct and this could also be the case and your answer here to "scan the directory and look for a file with that name but any extension" seems to be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call an incomplete path. You could try Digit's hack of looking through the directory for for a file that matches the name, or you could try looking for the file by adding the extensions to it, ie:

```
 $basePath = $ImagePath . $ImageName;
 if(file_exists($basePath . '.jpg'))
     $Ext = '.jpg';
 else if(file_exists($basePath . '.gif'))
     $Ext = '.gif';
 else if(file_exists($basePath . 'png'))
     $Ext = '.png';
 else
     $Ext = false;
```

Ugly hacks aside, the question begging to be asked is why are you storing them without the extensions? It would be easier to strip off the extension if you need to than it is try and find the file without the extension

Comment: You are absolutely correct leitning, however the code and database structure are not my design and changing them would probably break the system as it is and would certainly require heaps more coding. I am hoping to keep the system as it is (it certainly works well) and retrieve certain images to a new page, lets call the new page something like "Top Images" however getting those images is proving to be somewhat hard. I have checked and rechecked file path and file name and they are correct.

Comment: The following does produce the correct result but this is because I have added the file extension myself, so we know the image path and image name are correct however I can't use .jpg because some images will be .png or . bmp

<img src="<?php echo $ImagePath . $ImageName; ?>.jpg" width="100" height="100" >

What I am hoping to do is something like this:

<img src="<?php echo $ImagePath . $ImageName . $ImageExtension; ?>" width="100" height="100" >